# Retrieve data using a JPA statement when a global WHERE clause is set for all find methods in a Table Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using the following code in my table entity to filter out all the records with is_pooled = true. (`@Where(clause = "is_pooled = false")`)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bbser_inventory")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Where(clause = "is_pooled = false")
public class InventoryEntity extends BaseEntity {
```

But there is an exceptional case where I need to retrieve data with is_pooled value set as true in the database. How can I achieve this?

I already tried writing as following solutions but do not retrieve data

**Method 1**

```
List<InventoryEntity> findAllByInventoryIdInAndIsPooledTrue(List<Long> inventoryIdList);
```

**Method 2**

```
@Query("SELECT i FROM InventoryEntity i WHERE i.inventoryId IN (?1) AND i.isPooled = true")
List<InventoryEntity> findInventoryByIdAndIsPooled(Collection<Long> inventoryIds, Boolean ispooled);
```

Following is my serviceImpl method I am trying to retrieve this data

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> getPooledParentInfo(Long inventoryId) {
        PooledBloodInventoryEntity pooledBloodInventoryEntity = pooledInventoryRepository.findDistinctFirstByInventoryId(inventoryId);
        List<Long> pooledInventoryIdList = pooledBloodInventoryEntity.getParentInventoryIds();
        List<InventoryEntity> inventoryEntityList = inventoryRepository.findInventoryByIdAndIsPooled(pooledInventoryIdList, true);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(inventoryEntityList, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The example below will probably be useful. @Where annotation does not work in native queries

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT i.* FROM bbser_inventory i WHERE i.inventory_id IN (:inventoryIds) and i.is_pooled = true", nativeQuery = true)
List<InventoryEntity> findInventoryByIdAndIsPooled(Collection<Long> inventoryIds);
```

Comment: It is the problem as native queries aren't effective against @Where in this case how to get the results?

Comment: There is no solution to this problem that I know of. If you're using NativeQuery you need to add `is_pooled=false` to every query. By the way, did the solution I suggested above solve the problem?

Comment: it is not viable as there are more than 30 JPA statements

Comment: You asked that "there is an exceptional case where I need to retrieve data with is_pooled value set as true in the database. How can I achieve this?". if you try the above query you will see it works correctly. If there is any other problem, please write in detail.